# Don't understand "if" statements

Tags: python

I don't understand something about Python. This is binary search code and when i put `if` statement with return first it works, but when I put it below the another `if` statement something goes wrong. Could someone explain this?

```
def binary_search(arr, item):
    low = 0
    high = len(arr) - 1
    while low <= high:
        mid = (low+high)//2
        guess = arr[mid]
        if guess == item:
            return mid
        if guess > item:
            high = mid - 1

        else:
            low = mid + 1

    return None

arr = [1, 12, 16, 22, 24, 45, 54, 67, 89, 121]
print(binary_search(arr, 54))
```

Output: `6`

```
def binary_search(arr, item):
    low = 0
    high = len(arr) - 1
    while low <= high:
        mid = (low+high)//2
        guess = arr[mid]

        if guess > item:
            high = mid - 1
        if guess == item:
            return mid
        else:
            low = mid + 1

    return None

arr = [1, 12, 16, 22, 24, 45, 54, 67, 89, 121]
print(binary_search(arr, 54))
```

Output: **`None`**

I thought the operations python does in both cases are the same, but it seems I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to iterate the code you have by yourself. The second example would work like this:

```
0 | low = 0 high = 9 -> mid = 4
1 | low = 5 high = 9 -> mid = 7
2 | low = 8 high = 9 -> stop
```

If statements behave like this because your condition on `guess > item` and `guess < item` are not bound to each other meaning that they could be both checked and, therefore, run. This is what actually happens after third iteration, `high` should go lower and not the `low` higher

Answer (score 0):

Here I fixed it for you and it print out as your first code. if,elif and else are binded into one condition. It first check if then, elif and finally else.

```
def binary_search(arr, item):
    low = 0
    high = len(arr) - 1
    while low <= high:
        mid = (low+high)//2
        guess = arr[mid]

        if guess > item:
            high = mid - 1
        elif guess == item:
            return mid
        else:
            low = mid + 1

    return None

arr = [1, 12, 16, 22, 24, 45, 54, 67, 89, 121]
print(binary_search(arr, 54))
```